# Unable to build my project with Java 11 upgrade

Tags: java, java-8, ant, java-11

I am working in java desktop application that is currently using Java 1.8 and ant 1.9.9 for build. We are upgrading this application to support `openJdk11.0.2+9_` version. During build I am facing the below error.

```
[java] Total time: 11 seconds
 [java]     [javac] Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
 [java]     [javac] ----------
 [java]     [javac] 1. ERROR in ..\src\com\..\..\logging\Activator.java (at line 1)
 [java]     [javac]     package ...logging;
```

Comment: Are you jumping straight from 8 -> 11? Upgrade in steps 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11, then you can know exactly when the failure was introduced. There are migration guides for each step.

Comment: Ok, I try this way and update the comment. Please be watched :) Thanks @Michael

Comment: @Michael 8 and 11 are both LTS, it would make sense if you can do the migration without going through the intermediate versions, which are not supported any more.

Comment: @DidierL I have no idea what you're talking about. LTS is completely irrelevant... I'm not suggesting upgrade to Java 9 then deploy in production for 5 years. I'm suggesting to step through the versions one at a time locally so that you can pinpoint any issues. If you know the issue occurs between 8 and 9, you have a much better chance of finding the solution.

Comment: Check the ant build scripts for Java version checks - they seem to be one of your problems. If possible migrate to a current build system like gradle or maven.

Comment: @Robert, this is very stable and secure project and has high inter dependable jars and wars, all we written in various build scripts, so we had dropped our plan for migrating to new build systems.

Comment: @Michael, I am seeing the same error when I tried with Java 9 itself. I am completly blocked with this issue.

Comment: Show us entire stack trace

Comment: Is it possible for you to explicitly set `ant.build.javac.source` and `ant.build.javac.target` in your ant scripts? From the ant documentation: _"by default, no -source argument will be used at all unless the magic ant.build.javac.source property is set **Note that the default value depends on JDK that is running Ant. We highly recommend to always specify this attribute**"_ [https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html].

Comment: Thank you @skomisa, we are using source and target as jdk 11, and we installed the same version in our local machine. Yet it throws the same error.